# RTSP streaming to html5 video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

On a project, we have a camera with a RTSP stream (video & audio, encoded in H264). We need to make the stream available on all browsers (desktop & mobile).

I've seen some solutions:

- Convert the stream on HLS (iOS) and MPEG DASH (other browsers) with FFMPEG on a server
- Video only with [jsmpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg)

The problem is since we need a really live streaming (e.g. the user can record some pictures/video on live), a low the latency solution is a specification of the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you need low latency HLS is not a good solution.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely the problem...